# MobaXTerm opens the same connection twice instead of two different connections using command line option

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm attempting to run the following command from mobaxterm to open two new sessions in tabs

```
/cygdrive/c/mobaxterm/MobaXterm_Professional_8.6.exe -newtab ssh user:pass@thebes.domain.com && /cygdrive/c/mobaxterm/MobaXterm_Professional_8.6.exe -newtab ssh user:pass@sparta.domain.com
```

Only issue is, two tabs for thebes are open, instead of 1 for thebes and one for sparta.

What could be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out double quotes are necessary.

```
/cygdrive/c/mobaxterm/MobaXterm_Professional_8.6.exe -newtab "ssh user:pass@thebes.domain.com" && /cygdrive/c/mobaxterm/MobaXterm_Professional_8.6.exe -newtab "ssh user:pass@sparta.domain.com"
```